# Single-Digit Errors

Tags: cryptography

I've been assigned the following homework problem:

> Given an eight digit number $a_1a_2...a_8$ and a check digit $a_9$,
>
> $7a_1+3a_2+9a_3+7a_4+3a_5+9a_6+7a_7+3a_8+9a_9 \equiv 0 \mod{10}$
>
> This method detects all errors where only one digit is changed. Show that this is the case.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Because $3,7,9$ are relative prime to $10$ any single change will give a sum which is $\not \equiv 0 \pmod {10}$

Comment: How can I show this? :-)

Comment: Change one $a_k$ to $a_k + x$ with $x \ne 0.$ The the sum changes to $c x \pmod {10}$ with $c=3,7,9.$ But $cx$ cannot be a multiple of 10 and thus the change is $\not \equiv 0\pmod{10}.$

Comment: Ah! I understand what you're saying. Thank you very much for your help. :-)